# Does Base64 encoding-decoding(in Java) supports mathematical symbols?

Tags: java, encoding, base64, decode

I have a string containing mathematical symbols which I want to encode and decode in java.

I want to know whether encoding and decoding by 'Base64' will suffice for the same.

Can you please help me to know that 'Base64' supports mathematical symbols? like,

```
∞,π,∑,α,β,Ω, etc.
```

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

> Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation.

The important thing: it is about encoding **binary** data. Base64 doesn't care what that binary data is about. The only thing that matters is: when you rebuild your **String** objects, you have to understand the encoding that should be used.

In that sense: you really really want to read 
[this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) article by Joel Spolsky about encoding **strings**. It focuses on Unicode, but it should help you with understanding the difference between encoding binary data, and making sure that a **string** contains the **characters** you expect it to contain when printing for example.

Comment: Thank you!! this answer gave me an idea that how Base64 encoding works.
**I am not sure whether this would be another question-I am pasting here.**
Actually, Before encoding I am getting bytes of given string and then will proceed for encoding.
But, I am getting wrong value, when i get byte value of mathematical symbols like, "∑∞". 
for Ex.: Java code.
'//Consider this string which i want to encode.
String str = "m=∑∞";

public static byte[] printStringAsByte(String str)
{ 
 return str.getBytes();
}'
returned value: 109, 61, 63, 63

Whereas, 63 is ASCII code for question mark(?).

Comment: My suggestion: put up a new question, with exactly that content. But the point is: the byte values correspond to the string encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is one of generic encoding terms that encode binary data by treating it numerically and translating it into a base 64 representation.
Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data.

Hence,
Yes, we can encode the supported mathematical symbols using base 64 encoding.
Example, to get proper byte value of mathematical symbol you can use CharacterSet "UTF-8".

Here is my two Java methods to encode and decode the strings:

```
//imports
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

 public static String encode(String data){
        byte[] bytedata = null;
        try {
            bytedata = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String base64Binary = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytedata);
        /* for this example I am using DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary which is standard, you can use your own logic to encode it.
        */
        return base64Binary;
        }
        public static String decode(String base64Binary){

        byte[] bytedata = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Binary);
        /* Here again I have used standard decoding methods provided by java.
        You can write your own decoding logic based on your encoding style.
        */

        String decodedData = null;
        try {
            decodedData = new String(bytedata, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return decodedData;
        }
```